# How can I manage multiple versions of a React website?

Tags: reactjs, github, workflow, netlify

I have a React website that I'm hosting on Netlify but I want to deploy it in three stages.

Currently, I have a GitHub repository for it but I just push my local codes to the repo using GitHub Dekstop and it just goes live directly.

I would like to divide it into stages where I can first test the updates before going live to 'production'.

Is there a way to:

1. Push my local changes,
2. Decide on GitHub whether to make it testing or live?

I have heard about GitHub Action workflows and GitHub pages but I don't want to deploy with GitHub Pages.

I have also tried with Git workflow and configured the node.js workflow. But I still don't understand that how to manage the multiples stages with it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have at least two different Netlify deploys: one for testing and one for production. If so, you don't necessarily need a workflow.

**The easiest way** to set that up is to **use different branches.** Try these:

1. Ensure you have at least two separate branches on your repo e.g `main` for production and `dev` for development/testing
2. All changes you make to your code should be pushed to the `dev` branch.
3. Set up your test deploy on Netlify by choosing the repository but ensuring you choose the `dev` branch, as shown below.

[image: Netlify image]

4. This will now be the site that automatically shows any changes you push, instead of the site with the `main` branch for production.
5. If you are satisfied with the updates, you can then make a PR on GitHub to push your updates in the `dev` branch to your `main` branch.
   After merging the request, your updates will then reflect in your production deploy.

Hope that helps!✨